# Python conditional statement within a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

What is the best way to achieve having class attributes that change, based on input that has been passed in via a cli argument?

What I've written works perfectly fine, however feels overly messy and bad design. Is there a better way to go about this?

The example below has four different inputs, however as this program grows larger this would become very messy.

Here's some short example code;

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = None
        self.var3 = None
        self.var4 = None

        if var1 == 'foo':
            self.var2 = 'foo2'
            self.var3 = 'foo3'
            self.var4 = 'foo4'
        elif var1 == 'bar':
            self.var2 = 'bar2'
            self.var3 = 'bar3'
            self.var4 = 'bar4'
        elif var1 == 'foobar':
            self.var2 = 'foobar2'
            self.var3 = 'foobar3'
            self.var4 = 'foobar4'
        elif var1 == 'barfoo':
            self.var2 = 'barfoo2'
            self.var3 = 'barfoo3'
            self.var4 = 'barfoo4'


def main()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    example = Example(args.input)

    print(example.var2) # returns 'foo2'
```

Example of calling with an argument;

```
python main.py foo
```

Comment: Why not just do `self.var2 = self.var1 + "2"` and the same for the others? Also, why are you returning `self` from `__init___`?

Comment: You could use a dictionary that lists all the values for each possible `var1`.

Comment: You could create subclasses of Example, FooExample, BarExample , ... they'd have their own values defined, and the if, with a decicated method would return one of these class

Comment: @ddejohn I'm guessing those are examples, not literal values, so the concatenation doesn't work.

Comment: I sure hope so.

Comment: My apologies I've edited the example, returning self was a typo. Yes these are just examples, each of these variables would have completely different values. There could be dozens of different arguments so whilst the example is short, as the program matures this could get messy.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest providing a more representative example, as it's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do. There may be a better way but it's hard to discern your end goal at the moment.

Comment: It's easy to come up with syntax, but what you want here is to be thinking about semantics. What's the message you're sending to this class on setup, what does it mean? Answering that will help you figure out the answer to your question.

Comment: One possibility is to make `__init__` naive: just take 4 arguments, and set each attribute with the corresponding attribute. Then, instead of instantiating `Example` directly, always use a class method like `Example.as_foo()`, which can call `cls('foo', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4')` for you.

Comment: (Having distinct interfaces to a common but "private" `__init__` method is reminiscent of having separate subclasses of `Example` for each case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to keep `__init__` as "dumb" as possible, define separate class methods for each "style" of object, and push the burden of selecting the right class method to call to the caller.

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return cls('foo', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4')

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        return cls('bar', 'bar2', 'bar3', 'bar4')

    # etc

# Instead of Example('foo')
e = Example.foo()
```

The only thing you lose here is the ability to pass an unknown value to `Example` and get a properly initialized value back, for example,

```
x = "..."  # Assumed to be foo, bar, foobar, or barfoo
e = Example(x)
```

However, the caller can always use whatever method you might have hidden in side `Element.__init__` to pick the values for `var2` et al. to pick which class method to all. For example,

```
x = "foo"
e = getattr(Example, x)()  # e = Example.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to clean this up, as suggested in the comments. For something of the size and scale of your example, I would do something like this:

```py
class Example:
    _DEPENDENT_VALS = {
        'foo': ('foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'),
        'bar': ('bar2', 'bar3', 'bar4'),
        'foobar': ('foobar2', 'foobar3', 'foobar4'),
        'barfoo': ('barfoo2', 'barfoo3', 'barfoo4')
    }

    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = None
        self.var3 = None
        self.var4 = None

        if var1 in Example._DEPENDENT_VALS:
            self.var2, self.var3, self.var4 = Example._DEPENDENT_VALS[var1]
```

This method might not always be appropriate depending on the number and type of values you're setting but it's one way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
ls=['foo','bar','foobar','barfoo'] #adds the list of prefixes 

if self.var1 in ls:
    self.var2= f'{self.var1}2'
    self.var3= f'{self.var1}3'
    self.var4= f'{self.var1}4'
```

Comment: The OP indicated the suffix isn't predictably just `2`/`3`/`4`; it depends on the key, so you can't just hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `dict` mapping prefixes to a `tuple` of the three modifiers, then use it to initialize them:

```
class Example:
    _var_suffixes = {'foo': ('1', '2', '3'),
                     'bar': ('1', '2', '3'),
                     'foobar': ('1', '2', '3'),
                     'barfoo': ('1', '2', '3'),
                     }
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = None
        self.var3 = None
        self.var4 = None

        if var1 in self._var_suffixes:
            suf2, suf3, suf4 = self._var_suffixes[var1]
            self.var2 = var1 + suf2
            self.var3 = var1 + suf3
            self.var4 = var1 + suf4
```

Optionally, this may make more sense to store `var2` through `var4` as a `list` (especially if the number of suffixes is variable by key), in which case you'd do something like this, which is even simpler:

```
class Example:
    _var_suffixes = {'foo': ('1', '2'),
                     'bar': ('1', '2', '3'),
                     'foobar': ('1', '2', '3', '4'),
                     'barfoo': ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
                     }
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.varlist = []

        for suf in self._var_suffixes.get(var1, ()):
            self.varlist.append(var1 + suf)

    # Optional property for access by name
    @property
    def var2(self):
        try:
            return self.varlist[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

The class body is just Python code. It has specific scope rules, but anything goes otherwise. This means you can create functions conditionally:

```py
class C:
    if some_condition:
        def optional_method(self):
            pass
```

or pull methods from elsewhere:

```py
import some_module

class D:
    method_name = some_module.function_that_accepts_self
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if the best option but assuming that actual values aren `'foo1' 'foo2'` but something else or more complex I would go for updating the self.**dict**

Two ways (I think the seccond is more clear)

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        fooDict = {'var2':'foo2','var3':'foo3','var4':'foo4'}
        foovarDict = {'var2':'foovar2','var3':'foovar3','var4':'foovar4'}
        if var1 == 'foo':
            self.__dict__ = {**self.__dict__,**fooDict}
        elif var1 == 'foovar':
            self.__dict__ = {**self.__dict__,**foovarDict}
            
    def getVars(self):
        print(self.var1)
        print(self.var2)
        print(self.var3)
        print(self.var4)



a = A('foo')
a.getVars()

#ouputs
#foo
#foo2
#foo3
#foo4

b = A('foovar')
b.getVars()

#outputs
#foovar
#foovar2
#foovar3
#foovar4
```

Second way:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        fooDict = {'var2':'foo2','var3':'foo3','var4':'foo4'}
        foovarDict = {'var2':'foovar2','var3':'foovar3','var4':'foovar4'}
        if var1 == 'foo':
            self.__dict__.update(fooDict)
        elif var1 == 'foovar':
            self.__dict__.update(foovarDict)

    def getVars(self):
        print(self.var1)
        print(self.var2)
        print(self.var3)
        print(self.var4)

a = A('foo')
a.getVars()


b = A('foovar')
b.getVars()
```

with same outputs